# Conditionally copying and transposing data to new Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have set of Excel data in a sheet like this:

| Surname | Name | 2020-09-14 | 2020-09-15 | 2020-09-16 | 2020-09-17 | 2020-09-18 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Doe | John | attended |  | attended |  |  |
| Baby | Jane |  | attended |  | attended |  |

Is there a way via VBA or formulas to loop through each row and date cells in that row and copy user data to a new sheet if 'attended' is entered in the date column?

Resulting table in a new sheet would look like this:

| Surname | Name | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Doe | John | 2020-09-14 |
| Doe | John | 2020-09-16 |
| Baby | Jane | 2020-09-15 |
| Baby | Jane | 2020-09-17 |

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of excel do you have? Office365 will easier your work with excel formulas only.

Comment: I have Excel 2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the first answer said, we don't know where your data is. I assumed that your data will be on "Sheet1". Here is VBA code that you can use to copy your raw data into a new sheet. Each time you run the code, it deletes all sheets other than sheet 1, then create a new sheet named "Attended", and lastly, it loops through your data, copy 'Surname', 'Name' ,and 'Date' into the new sheet "Attended".

```
Sub TransposeData()

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lastcol As Long
Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range


lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lastcol = Sheet1.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

'Delete all worksheets other than Sheet1
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Sheet1" Then
        ws.Delete
    End If
Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

'Create a new worksheet
Sheets.Add(after:=Sheet1).Name = "Attended"
With Sheets("Attended")
    .Range("A1") = "Surname"
    .Range("B1") = "Name"
    .Range("C1") = "Date"
End With


'Loop through datatable to get names if attended is entered and copy them to the new sheet
i = 2

With Sheet1
    For Each cell In .Range("a1", .Cells(lastrow, lastcol))
        If cell = "attended" Then
            .Cells(cell.Row, 1).Copy Sheets("Attended").Cells(i, 1) 'Copy Surname to the new sheet
            .Cells(cell.Row, 2).Copy Sheets("Attended").Cells(i, 2) 'Copy Name to the new sheet
            .Cells(1, cell.Column).Copy Sheets("Attended").Cells(i, 3) 'Copy Date to the new sheet
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, works like a charm!

I liked Simon's solution aswell, but yours was bit easier to read and to understand for me :)

Answer (score 1):

I have this I just made for you in VBA. You didn't provide any information about where your data is so I've left as per my testing. You will need to change it to the relevant columns/rows etc.

Otherwise you could update your question with more info and I can edit the necessary parts. For example, is the amount of dates known or does it fluctuate and if it does fluctuate then is finding the last row ok or is there other data beyond these dates that isn't included etc.

```
Sub TransposeData()

Dim lrow As Long, lcol As Long, ws As Worksheet, i As Long, cell As Range, r As Long

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change to your sheet name
lrow = ws.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Change H to relevant column
lcol = ws.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'Change 1 to relevant row
r = 2 'starting row to transpose data to

With ws
    For i = 2 To lrow
        For Each cell In .Range("J" & i, .Cells(i, lcol)) 'Change J to starting column of the dates (After Surname/Name)
            If cell.Value <> "" Then 'Checks if cell is not blank. AKA they attended
                .Range("A" & r) = .Range("H" & i) 'Change A and H should be your Surname columns
                .Range("B" & r) = .Range("I" & i) 'B and I should be your First Name Columns
                .Range("C" & r) = .Cells(1, cell.Column) 'C will be your date column, change the 1 to which row has the dates in them
                r = r + 1
            End If
        Next
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```